# How to compile FFmpeg as static (single file)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

I would like to compile FFmpeg 4.1.3 as static or single file, After compiled. It's shared binary.

Here is what I do

**Install the dependencies**

```
apt-get -y install build-essential autoconf automake cmake libtool git \
checkinstall nasm yasm libass-dev libfreetype6-dev libsdl2-dev libtool \
libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev \
libxcb-xfixes0-dev pkg-config texinfo wget zlib1g-dev libchromaprint-dev \
frei0r-plugins-dev ladspa-sdk libcaca-dev libcdio-paranoia-dev \
libcodec2-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libfribidi-dev libgme-dev \
libgsm1-dev libjack-dev libmodplug-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev \
libopencore-amrwb-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libopenmpt-dev libopus-dev \
libpulse-dev librsvg2-dev librubberband-dev librtmp-dev libshine-dev \
libsmbclient-dev libsnappy-dev libsoxr-dev libspeex-dev libssh-dev \
libtesseract-dev libtheora-dev libtwolame-dev libv4l-dev libvo-amrwbenc-dev \
libvpx-dev libwavpack-dev libwebp-dev libx264-dev libx265-dev \
libxvidcore-dev libxml2-dev libzmq3-dev libzvbi-dev liblilv-dev libmysofa-dev \
libopenal-dev opencl-dev gnutls-dev libfdk-aac-devre
```

**prepare FFmpeg source code**

```
wget https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/archive/n4.1.3.tar.gz
tar -xvf n4.1.3.tar.gz
cd FFmpeg-n4.1.3
```

**Build**

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-filters --enable-openssl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version=Patrickz
```

then make & make install

**Compile passed, but it is shared binary. Any solutions or suggestion please.**

Comment: Well, the packages you download often only provide dynamic version. (see https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libopenmpt-dev/filelist for instance : only `.so` file, no `.a` file. To construct a static executable, you will need to build all dependency as static. Apparently, someone already did it: https://github.com/zimbatm/ffmpeg-static